# How can i reverse proxy using Titanium-Web-Proxy?

Tags: proxy, titanium-web-proxy

I have used Titanium-Web-Proxy for reverse proxy. where i can specify server back-end Ip Address?. I have added end point and also the service started with endpoint. But it could not  connect with backend IP Address.
[Titanium-Web-Proxy](https://github.com/justcoding121/Titanium-Web-Proxy)

```
public void StartProxy()
        {
            proxyServer.BeforeRequest += OnRequest;
            proxyServer.BeforeResponse += OnResponse;
            proxyServer.ServerCertificateValidationCallback += OnCertificateValidation;
            proxyServer.ClientCertificateSelectionCallback += OnCertificateSelection;


            var transparentEndPoint = new TransparentProxyEndPoint(IPAddress.Parse("x.x.x.x"), 5001, true)
            {
                GenericCertificateName = "test"

            };

            proxyServer.UpStreamHttpProxy = new ExternalProxy() { HostName = "x.x.x.x", Port = 5000};
            proxyServer.AddEndPoint(transparentEndPoint);
            proxyServer.Start();



        }
```

please any one help me to add backend IP and provide a samples to authenticate backend IP.

Thanks,
Selva

Comment: Are you sending HTTP traffic?  There seem to be bugs in the current version with HTTP.  Also I believe you should use your BeforeRequest handler to change the URI to the backend IP that you want to send the request to.  I'm figuring this out as I go, so I could be wrong.

Answer (score 1):

In addition to my comments about the current version (2016/10/06) which they call 1.0.1 in the assembly properties.  I believe the intended way to change requests to a backend server is through the BeforeRequest event handler, eg.

```
    public async Task OnRequest(object sender, SessionEventArgs e)
    {

        string newhost = "http://localhost";
        Uri u = e.WebSession.Request.RequestUri;
        e.WebSession.Request.RequestUri = new Uri(newhost + u.AbsolutePath);

    }
```